# How to check if a circle lies in a certain range

Tags: geometry, circles, education, matlab, image-processing

[image: Please check me]

I've a problem where I need to calculate the score on this board. I was able to detect the ranges, and detect the bullets.
I would like to make a loop to check whether the bullet holes that are marked with small circles are inside a certain range with a for a loop. I've the radii of the big circles or ranges, and also have the radii of the small circles or bullets. I just need a general loop that will check them all and tell me for example if bullet 1 marking exist in range 1  or 2 or 3..etc.  I am using Matlab but I just want to know the procedure.

Comment: How is that question different from [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4343503/446262) post by you a few hours ago?

Comment: First one I needed a general algorithm to detect the ranges, second one I manually detected the ranges without a general algorithm, and would like to know how to calculate where each bullet lie between which range. provided Ive the radii of the large circles, and small circles.

Comment: This is a programming problem, rather than mathematical one, no?

Comment: If you have the centers of circles and radii, just measure distance between centers and compare to sum of radii.